# UIActivityIndicator not appearing in Search View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UIActivityIndicator` set up in storyboard like so

[image]

I have checked that the IBOutlet is set up properly, but the view still doesn't appear.

I've tried adding the following, but no change.

```
  _spinner.hidden = NO;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_spinner];
    _spinner.center = self.view.center;
    [_spinner startAnimating];
```

I also tried adding the ActivityIndicator as a subview of the Search View Controller, but Storyboard wouldn't let me.

Also strange is that when I tried hiding the tableview before showing the spinner, the corresponding portion of the screen was black.

Comment: I don't see code `[self.view addSubview:_spinner];`, don't see code where you set _spinner's frame or autolayout constraints.

Comment: just for info, if it is IBOutlet of interface builder should it be added as a subview?

Comment: I was also wondering about that, since interface builder usually takes care of it for you.  But in this case, there was no content view in IB to which I could add the subview, so I think that's why I had to explicitly add the code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code above in **ViewDidLoad**. And make sure **animating** property in the interface builder is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

While seeing your image..

I think the search view controller is hiding the activity indicator view.

So, Keep the activity indicator view on top of table view of search view controller or

on top of search view controller at Interface Builder..

Hope it helps you..

If still not fixed..Please post entire code where you initialized activity indicator view at your implementation..(.m)